# DataView row Filtering

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0

I have two `DataView` that I am trying to sort, in dgtest1 I am trying to for the exception of the data that contains a `Typeid != 25` and in dgtest2 I am trying to only show the data where `Typeid == 25`.

When I step through the code I am throwing an error on saying

> "Cannot interpret token '!' at position 6".

Can someone show me how to properly use the string row filter?

The parameters are (Data Table table, string RowFilter, string Sort, DataViewRowState)

```
dgtest1.ItemsSource = new DataView(dttest1, "Typeid!= 25", "", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
dgtest2.ItemsSource = new DataView(dttest1, "Typeid == 25", "", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
```

Comment: Use `<>` for "not equal".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct syntax to use for the RowFilter expression in the first Dataview constructor is

```
dgtest1.ItemsSource = new DataView(dttest1, "Typeid <> 25", "", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
                                                    ^^
```

in the second one you need to use

```
dgtest2.ItemsSource = new DataView(dttest1, "Typeid = 25", "", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
```

The syntax used for the RowFilter parameter in the DataView constructor is the same used for the property [Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx) of the DataColumn and it is not like the equality operator of C#

**EDIT** Following your comment below. If Typeid is a database field of text datatype then you need to enclose the value used in the RowFilter between single quotes

```
dgtest1.ItemsSource = new DataView(dttest1, "Typeid <> '25'", "", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
dgtest2.ItemsSource = new DataView(dttest1, "Typeid = '25'", "", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
```

However this seems a little strange. If the Typeid field contains numbers it should be defined as a numeric datatype.

Comment: when i use the syntax i get the following {"Cannot perform '<>' operation on System.String and System.Int32."}

Comment: if TypeID is a string (in the database) then you need to use quotes around the value. But something doesn't seems right here. Are you sure that TypeID is a field of your table?

Comment: some more info when sql returns the data i dump it into dttest1

Comment: dttest1 = m_dsTherapy.Tables[1];